# How to check sql query for correctness of schema before it gets executed

Tags: mysql, sql, mybatis

we do not have a database schema versioning yet in our system, just wanted to know if there is way to check all the sql queries available in our system for their schema correctness (not syntactical correctness).

Requirement is to check that tables / columns mentioned in the query are available in the current database version, so that errors can be found out while starting the service.

We are using mysql and mybatis.

Comment: For `SELECT` statment you can verify that MySQL response without error if you prefix [`EXPLAIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/explain.html) otherwise you can use `EXPLAIN` and the `information_schema` to determine the which columns are present. Sadly I don't know how to adopt this to mybatis; but maybe somebody else can build upon this... ?

Answer (score 0):

In your *mapper* file, when defining all of your *SQL* statements, you could create an equivalent one of the same name with *Verify* (or similar) appended to the name which checks the `information_schema` to determine present columns. You could then call all of these *Verify* queries during startup to see if they complete.

Another approach (which I think may ultimately be cleaner and potentially more thorough) would be setup a series of tests using *TestNG* or *Spock* or similar (I prefer *Spock*, although that uses *Groovy*, so may not be ideal for your situation) which run all of the *mapper* statements involved.

If you get an exception in the test because one or more columns aren't present, there will be an exception from the *JDBC* driver, and so the test will fail. In addition, if as part of the tests you add the expected results of the queries, you will also test the accuracy/behavior of the queries, so you will be able to notice if that later changes (and causes test failures) if the code changes.